# onSsignal ionic set up server for client push notification

Tags: ionic-framework, server, onesignal

I am trying to create client to client push. After talking to an engineer on the oneSignal team, I was informed that "We do not have Butt code like Parse so you need to make a create notification REST API POST call to our server to from your system/server to create a notification pragmatically."

I am trying to create a server to call REST API POST call to oneSignal, but as someone who is so new to the server idea, I am lost. Can anyone give me a little idea regarding how to create an ionic server?

I have a basic idea after reading this post. https://www.airpair.com/ionic-framework/posts/push-notifications-using-ionic-framework, but I am still a bit confuse how to set it up with Haruku or just in general the idea of a server with ionic?

Comment: Are you using Parse?

Comment: No, because Parse only has Parse server now and it does not support client push due to security reason